# iOS Swift: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation resets between roations

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cgaffinetransform

I am using a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` to rotate a view. When I release the view, then start again, it snaps to the `Identity` rotation before going back to rotating. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to smoothly continue with the next rotation event. The only question I can find bout this, here, went unanswered years ago.

I can port from Obj-C if anyone is more comfortable responding that way.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious, but you're my only hope, Obi Wan Stackoverflow.

```
func rotateToRotate(rotationRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    let rotation = rotationRecognizer.rotation
    if rotationRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0 + self.lastRotation)
        return
    }

    if rotationRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)
        self.lastRotation = rotation
        return
    }

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that autocomplete tripped me up here. `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` is *not* the same thing as `CGAffineTransformRotate`. The former doesn't change the `CGAffineTransformIdentity`, the latter does.

Corrected code:

```
func rotateToRotate(rotationRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    let rotation = rotationRecognizer.rotation
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.view.transform, rotation)
    rotationRecognizer.rotation = 0.0
}
```